# Rollup.js will not include the node module discord-rpc in the bundle. Is there anyway to do this?

Tags: typescript, discord, rollupjs, discord-rpc

I'm only importing discord-rpc and only have `main.ts`. Also using rollup plugins typscript and node-resolve.

`main.ts` import:

```
const { Client } = require("discord-rpc");
```

`package.json` scripts and dependencies:

```
{
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "rollup --config rollup.config.js -w",
    "build": "rollup --config rollup.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^15.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^9.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.2",
    "obsidian": "https://github.com/obsidianmd/obsidian-api/tarball/master",
    "rollup": "^2.32.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "discord-rpc": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

`rollup.config.js`:

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import {nodeResolve} from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  input: [
    'main.ts',
  ],
  output: {
    dir: '.',
    sourcemap: 'inline',
    format: 'cjs',
    exports: 'default'
  },
  external: ['obsidian', 'electron'],
  plugins: [
    typescript(),
    commonjs(),
    nodeResolve({browser: true}),
  ]
};
```

Do I need to use an alternative to rollup.js?

**Edit:**
I tried changing `const { Client } = require("discord-rpc");` to `import { Client } from "discord-rpc";` but I still get `Error: Cannot find module 'discord-rpc'`

**Edit 2:**
Keeping this change:

```
import { Client } from "discord-rpc";
```

I edited `rollup.config.js`:

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import {nodeResolve} from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  input: [
    'main.ts',
  ],
  output: {
    dir: '.',
    sourcemap: 'inline',
    format: 'cjs',
    exports: 'default'
  },
  external: ['obsidian', 'electron'],
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({browser: true}), // Moving this up.
    typescript(),
    commonjs(),
  ]
};
```

No longer get this Error in runtime:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'discord-rpc'
```

But I get this during build:

```
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
timers (imported by node_modules/discord-rpc/src/client.js, timers?commonjs-external)
events (imported by node_modules/discord-rpc/src/client.js, events?commonjs-external, node_modules/discord-rpc/src/transports/ipc.js, node_modules/discord-rpc/src/transports/websocket.js)
```

It also doesn't work as expect but I'm not sure if that's due to my code or rollup...

Comment: D̵o̵e̵s̵ ̵r̵o̵l̵l̵u̵p̵ ̵e̵v̵e̵n̵ ̵s̵u̵p̵p̵o̵r̵t̵ ̵`̵r̵e̵q̵u̵i̵r̵e̵`̵?̵ (I see you have added CJS) What happens if you use ES import instead: `import { Client } from 'discord-rpc';` ?

Comment: Thank you but I tried it (`import { Client } from "discord-rpc";`) but I still get `Error: Cannot find module 'discord-rpc'`. Is there another option to rollup?

Comment: looks to me like `nodeResolve` should appear higher-up in the order of `plugins`... definitely above `commonjs`

Comment: Interesting. So I moved nodeResolve() above typescript() and it no longer gives errors. However I get build errors. Edit 2

Comment: ... after `typescript()` but before `commonjs()`?

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it doesn't work... However I have fixed almost every error. And I will create an answer soon. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I solved the problem!

I had to move a few things around:
`rollup.config.js`:

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import {nodeResolve} from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  input: [
    'main.ts',
  ],
  output: {
    dir: '.',
    sourcemap: 'inline',
    format: 'cjs',
    exports: 'default'
  },
  external: ['obsidian', 'electron', 'net', 'events', 'timers'],
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({browser: true, preferBuiltins: false}),
    typescript(),
    commonjs(),
  ]
};
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/discord-rpc": "^3.0.4",
    "discord-rpc": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

`main.ts` import:

```
import { Client } from "discord-rpc";
```